# All my UI suddenly become unresponsive after allow permission from from permission dialog

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which require location permission to work, right after the permission dialog pops up, my apps begin to show the UI of my app, but then when I tap on the GO button, the button won't respond to my action and just sit there and do nothing, until I restart my apps, everything just begin to work normally and my button started to be responsive again.

This is my activity:

[image]

Below is my activity code:

```
  public class ParStuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_par_stu);

            dcounter = 0;
            searchbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
            searchedt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchpar);
            autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


            buildGoogleApiClient();

            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());


            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }else{
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000, 10, this);
            }

            searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    url = "https://www.tuitionathome.my/inc/myMobileDL.php?Operation=getTutors&lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&search=" + searchedt2.getText().toString();
                    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(ParStuActivity.this);
    // Creating volley request obj
                    maps.clear();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ParStuActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Hold On....");
                    pDialog.show();
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i("Respond : ", response.toString());
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            int totalRecords = 1;
                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = -1; i < totalRecords; i++) {
                                try {

                                    final int i2 = 0;

                                    JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("dataTable");
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                                    final String markerurl = jsonObject.getString("iconPath");
                                    double lat3 = jsonObject.getDouble("lat");
                                    double lng3 = jsonObject.getDouble("lng");
                                    final String title = jsonObject.getString("userName");
                                    final String subtitle = jsonObject.getString("address");
                                    final LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat3, lng3);


                                    if (markerurl.contains("null")) {
                                        maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .title(title)
                                                .snippet(subtitle)
                                                .position(sydney));
                                    } else {
                                        final Bitmap[] bmp = new Bitmap[1];
                                        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                URL url;
                                                try {
                                                    url = new URL(markerurl);
                                                    bmp[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        Marker marker = maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                                .position(sydney)
                                                                .title(title)
                                                                .snippet(subtitle)
                                                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp[0].createScaledBitmap(bmp[0], 100, 100, false))));
                                                        mHashMap.put(marker, i2);

                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                        thread.start();

                                    }


                                    totalRecords = Integer.valueOf(response.getString("recordsTotal"));
                                    Log.i("Total records", response.getString("recordsTotal"));

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            pDialog.dismiss();

                            new AlertDialog.Builder(ParStuActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("Error")
                                    .setMessage("Internet connection error")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            // continue with delete

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .show();


                        }
                    });

                    // Adding request to request queue
                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);


                }
            });



            autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.

                    String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                            + place.getId() + "\n"
                            + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                            + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                            + place.getAttributions();
                    System.out.print("Place: " + place.getName() + placeDetailsStr);


                    lat = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
                    lng = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude, place.getLatLng().longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()


                    if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

                        autocompleteFragment.setText(city);

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ParStuActivity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("cityname", city);
                        editor.putString("lat", lat);
                        editor.putString("lng", lng);
                        editor.apply();
                        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
                        mapFragment.getMapAsync(ParStuActivity.this);
                                            }


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    System.out.print("An erroe occured " + status);
                }
            });


        }


        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {

            if (lat == null && lng == null) {
                System.out.print("location null");
            } else {
                double latd = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                double lngd = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                LatLng testloc = new LatLng(latd, lngd);
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(testloc, 13));
            }


            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    final String username = marker.getTitle();
                    final double lat2 = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                    final double lng2 = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                    url23 = "https://www.tuitionathome.my/inc/myMobileDL.php?Operation=getTutors&lat=" + lat2 + "&lng=" + lng2 + "&search=" + username.replace(" ", "%20");
                    Log.i("URL23", url23);

                    Log.i("Lat", String.valueOf(lat2));
                    Log.i("lng", String.valueOf(lng2));
    // Creating volley request obj
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ParStuActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Hold On....");
                    pDialog.show();
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    JsonObjectRequest movieReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url23,
                            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i("respond test length", response.toString());
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ParStuActivity.this, TutorView.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("dataTable");
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String ttID = jsonObject.getString("recId");

                                    Log.i("ttID test", ttID);
                                    Log.i("lat", String.valueOf(lat2));
                                    Log.i("lng", String.valueOf(lng2));
                                    Log.i("USERNAME", username.toString());

                                    LatLng distanceloc = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng));
                                    LatLng markerloc = new LatLng(lat2, lng2);
                                    CalculationByDistance(distanceloc, markerloc);

                                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ParStuActivity.this);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString("TTID", ttID);
                                    editor.putString("itemname", username.toString());
                                    editor.apply();


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            pDialog.dismiss();

                            new AlertDialog.Builder(ParStuActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("Error")
                                    .setMessage("Internet connection error")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            // continue with delete
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .show();


                        }
                    });

                    // Adding request to request queue
                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
                }
            });
            // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ParStuActivity.this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Should we show an explanation?
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ParStuActivity.this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ParStuActivity.this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            2);

                } else {

                    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ParStuActivity.this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            2);

                    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                    // result of the request.
                }
            } else {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }


            maps = map;
        }




        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 2: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                        // contacts-related task you need to do.
                        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
                        mapFragment.getMapAsync(ParStuActivity.this);
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                            return;
                        } else {
                            maps.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                                    mGoogleApiClient);

                            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                                alatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                                alongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                                LatLng aloc = new LatLng(alatitude, alongitude);
                                maps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(aloc, 13));
                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                        Toast.makeText(ParStuActivity.this, "Permission access to current locarion denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    break;
                }
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); // Update location every second

            LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Criteria crit = new Criteria();
            crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ParStuActivity.this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            } else {
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        5000, 10, this);

                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                        mGoogleApiClient);

                if (mLastLocation != null) {
                    alatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                    alongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                    lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                    lng = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());


                }
            }

            if (dcounter == 0) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ParStuActivity.this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    dcounter++;

                    LatLng aloc = new LatLng(alatitude, alongitude);
                    maps.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(aloc, 13));
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(alatitude, alongitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()


                    if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        autocompleteFragment.setText(city);

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ParStuActivity.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("cityname", city);
                        editor.putString("lat", lat);
                        editor.putString("lng", lng);
                        editor.apply();
                    }


                }
            } else {

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            alatitude = location.getLatitude();
            alongitude = location.getLongitude();
            lng = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(alatitude, alongitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()


            if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

                autocompleteFragment.setText(city);

                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ParStuActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("cityname", city);
                editor.putString("lat", lat);
                editor.putString("lng", lng);
                editor.apply();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
        synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();


        }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

   }


    @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

       }
        }
```

Comment: Are you doing anything that can block the UI thread after the permission is granted?

Comment: i don't think so that i've block the UI thread.

Comment: have you ever got the answer, i think I am also getting same problem